# php regex not working, returning subject string instead of regex result

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex, xpath

i'm struggling to make a php regex work.

doing the regex in javascript works:

scenario 1 : javascript regex

in php:
I get the node value through xpath:

```
$yearNode = $xpath->query(".//h2/a", $node)[0];
$year = $yearNode->nodeValue;
```

i add it to the json ajax response:

```
$responseStr[$i]['year'] = $year;
```

I regex the response in javascript:

```
var year = results[j]['year'].match("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");
```

this works fine but if I try in php:

scenario 2 : php

```
$yearNode = $xpath->query(".//h2/a", $node)[0];
$yearMatches = preg_match("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", $yearNode, $matches);
$year = $matches[0][0];
$responseStr[$i]['year'] = $year;
```

then try to get the result in javascript:

```
var year = results[j]['year'];
```

I get the whole subject string instead of the regex match, which is the equivalent of the php json response in scenario 1, ie

```
$yearNode = $xpath->query(".//h2/a", $node)[0];
```

what is wrong ? I've read some docs on php regex like http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php but can't make it work

I think I'm probably misinterpreting the result array of the php regex

```
$year = $matches[0][0];
```

I've tried many combinations to test all the items inside the array like

$year = $matches[x][0];

or

$year = $matches[0][x];

but cannot retrieve the exact 4 digit (year) expected result that I easily get in the javascript regex in scenario 1.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Regex delimiters. And `print_r()` to see what $matches contains.

Comment: what do you mean by regex delimiters ? and you mean to replace the echo with print_r ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `/` before and after your Regex:

```
$yearMatches = preg_match("/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/", $yearNode, $matches);
```

Preferably, add the start `^` and end `$` boundaries:

```
$yearMatches = preg_match("/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/", $yearNode, $matches);
```

Comment: Would be even better if you add the start `^` and end `$` boundaries and make sure that `$yearMatches === 1`.

Comment: thanks i tried it result is weird, this works :   
        $yearNode = $xpath->query($yearXpath, $node)[0];
        $year = $yearNode->nodeValue;
        $yearMatches = preg_match("/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/", $year,  
        $matches);<br>
here I don't try to access the result so I get the original string as expected but if I add :      
        $year = $matches[0];    
then i get a json parse ajax fail

Comment: i think the issue is in $year = $matches[0]; i can't figure out how to use the result of the regex

Answer (score 2):

ok it was probably semantics but this works

```
$yearMatches = preg_match("/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/", $title, $matches);
$year = $matches[0];
```

(removed ^ and $ because the 4 digit number is within a string)

thanks !